# How do I use Flutter Textfield in CupertinoTabView without causing an exception when tapped?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a simple flutter app for iOS.

My end goal is to have a CupertinoTabView that has a square image at the top with a textfield underneath that will slide up into view above the keyboard when tapped to allow the user to enter some text.

When I integrate 'standard' working code into the iOS specific widgets, and tap the textfield, I get an exception and the textfield does not move.

I'm using the following version of flutter:

```
Flutter 0.2.3 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5a58b36e36 (3 weeks ago) • 2018-03-13 13:20:13 -0700
Engine • revision e61bb9ac3a
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.35.flutter-290c576264
```

I've created some code to demonstrate the problem.

This **working** code can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nuxibyte/e11df7abd3bfed392b18fb55e4529a3e):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Widget createTextFieldListView(){
    return new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Add text here"),
        ),
        new AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ].toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("textfield")),
      body: createTextFieldListView(),
    );
  }
}
```

This **failing** iOS code can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nuxibyte/9abd551217eb3781b67e0f04f2b34fe4):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Widget createTextFieldListView(){
    return new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Add text here"),
        ),
        new AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ].toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: new CupertinoTabBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("One")),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Two")),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Three")),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new CupertinoTabView(builder: (BuildContext context){
          return new CupertinoPageScaffold(
            navigationBar: new CupertinoNavigationBar(),
            child: createTextFieldListView(),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This **exception** message can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nuxibyte/f8a31650d156b3f5a1f5c4e931c9d015)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "<removed>"
Running Xcode clean...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done
Installing and launching...
Syncing files to device iPhone...
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
'package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart': Failed assertion: line 41: 'controller != null': is
not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      new InteractiveInkFeature (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:41)
#3      new InkSplash (package:flutter/src/material/ink_splash.dart:130)
#4      _InkSplashFactory.create (package:flutter/src/material/ink_splash.dart:61)
#5      _TextFieldState._createInkFeature (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:366)
#6      _TextFieldState._startSplash (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:405)
#7      _TextFieldState._handleTapDown (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:384)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkDown.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:142)
#9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102)
#10     TapGestureRecognizer._checkDown (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:142)
#11     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:121)
#12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156)
#13     BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147)
#14     BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121)
#15     BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101)
#16     BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64)
#17     BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48)
#18     _invoke1 (file:///Users/errolc/code/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/hooks.dart:134)
#19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (file:///Users/errolc/code/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/hooks.dart:91)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)

Handler: onTapDown
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#ddee3(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, finalPosition: Offset(80.0,
  402.0))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: What is the version of Flutter? It may be solved with this fix https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/14431 on 22 Feb.

Comment: @najeira Added version info to the question. I'll take a look at the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone on [gitter](https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter) for helping solve this, especially [xqwzts](https://github.com/xqwzts)

> ...the problem is that TextField is a material widget: It has an InkWell which expects to find an anscestor piece of material to print its ripples on.
>   Usually you would have this by using a MaterialApp ancestor

To prevent the exception being thrown it's possible to wrap the `TextField` in a `Material` widget. Although this fixes the exception the `CupertinoTabScaffold` doesn't have the functionality to slide the `Textfield` up over the keyboard (yet).